# PHP, SQL Code not working

Tags: php, sql

im ranning into some problems agian, and hope that your guys can help me.

I have this code, that i can't get to work.

see, the strange thing is, if i change

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($dblogin, 
    "SELECT * FROM devices 
        RIGHT JOIN repair ON devices.name = repair.modelid 
        WHERE repair.modelid=$check");
```

to

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($dblogin, 
    "SELECT * FROM devices 
        RIGHT JOIN repair ON devices.name = repair.modelid 
        WHERE repair.modelid LIKE %iPad%");
```

i will work, just fine :-/

im really lost, and i tryed, to echo the $check, to see if there was an error in the $check variable. but thats works just fine.

```
<div id="slidingDiv<?=$row["id"] ?>" class="toggleDiv row-fluid single-project">
   <div class="span6">
      <img src="adm/images/<?=$row["image"] ?>" alt="project <?=$row["id"] ?>" />
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
      <div class="project-description">
         <div class="project-title clearfix">
            <h3><?=$row["name"] ?></h3>
            <span class="show_hide close">
            <i class="icon-cancel"></i>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div class="project-info">
            <?php
               $check = $row["name"];
               $query2 = mysqli_query($dblogin, 
               "SELECT * FROM devices 
                   RIGHT JOIN repair ON devices.name = repair.modelid 
                   WHERE repair.modelid=$check");
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2))
                          {
                          ?>
            <div>
               <span><?=$row["price"] ?> ,-</span><?=$row["name"] ?>
            </div>
            <?php
               }
               ?>
            <div>
               <span>Client</span>Some Client Name
            </div>
            <div>
               <span>Date</span>July 2013
            </div>
            <div>
               <span>Skills</span>HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript
            </div>
            <div>
               <span>Link</span>http://examplecomp.com
            </div>
         </div>
         <p>Believe in yourself! Have faith in your abilities! Without a humble but reasonable confidence in your own powers you cannot be successful or happy.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If i changes it, to this, it runs just fine

```
<?
   $query = mysqli_query($dblogin, "select * from brands ORDER BY id");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
   ?>
<li class="filter" data-filter="<?=$row["name"] ?>">
   <a href="#noAction"><img class="aimg" style="height:50px;" src="adm/images/<?=$row["image"] ?>" /></a>
</li>
<?
   }
   ?>
</ul>
<!-- Start details for portfolio project 1 -->
<div id="single-project">
<?
   $query = mysqli_query($dblogin, "select * from devices ORDER BY name DESC");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
              {
              ?>        
<div id="slidingDiv<?=$row["id"] ?>" class="toggleDiv row-fluid single-project">
   <div class="span6">
      <img src="adm/images/<?=$row["image"] ?>" alt="project <?=$row["id"] ?>" />
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
      <div class="project-description">
         <div class="project-title clearfix">
            <h3><?=$row["name"] ?></h3>
            <span class="show_hide close">
            <i class="icon-cancel"></i>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div class="project-info">
            <?php
               $check = $row["name"];
               $query2 = mysqli_query($dblogin, "select * from devices right join repair on devices.name = repair.modelid WHERE repair.modelid LIKE '%iPhone 6%'");
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2))
                          {
                          ?>
            <div>
               <span><?=$row["price"] ?> ,-</span><?=$row["name"] ?>
            </div>
            <?php
               }
               ?>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?
   }
   ?>
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT * FROM devices
  RIGHT JOIN repair ON devices.name = repair.modelid
  WHERE repair.modelid LIKE '%iPhone 6%'
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Gives this result

```
id  name    brand   image   model-id    id  name    modelid price   brand   date
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       217 Front Glas Udskiftning  iPhone 6    1300        1432215986
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       218 Bagside (komplet)   iPhone 6    2500        1432216016
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       219 TÃ¦nd/sluk Udskiftning  iPhone 6    500     1432216041
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       220 Homeknap    iPhone 6    500     1432216064
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       221 Ã˜rehÃ¸jtaler   iPhone 6    500     1432216085
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       222 Ladestik    iPhone 6    500     1432216107
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       223 Batteri iPhone 6    500     1432216124
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       224 Vibrator    iPhone 6    500     1432216136
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       225 Mikrofon    iPhone 6    500     1432216165
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       226 Kamera  iPhone 6    500     1432216177
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       227 HÃ¸jtaler (musik/lyd)   iPhone 6    500     1432216191
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       228 WIFI Antenne    iPhone 6    500     1432218537
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       229 Jackstik    iPhone 6    500     1432218564
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       230 Jailbreak   iPhone 6    500     1432218593
7   iPhone 6    Apple   iphone6_small.jpg       231 Bagside (komplet)   iPhone 6    2500        1432218612
```

Comment: What happens when you run raw query to the database? Do you get result?

Comment: Yes, if i change where='%ipad%' it works just fine

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the raw query you run against the database

Comment: Done i think , it is postet in the my first post

Comment: No. I mean post the sql query you use in your db client (phpmyadmin, etc...), not php code.

Comment: i think i postet the right now. Yes it is a 100% match, it is created, usede the admin panel, with forms, :-/

Comment: So last php hardcoded query doesn't return result?

Comment: the hardcoded one, gives a result, but the one with the ='$check dossent :-/ and the value of check, is pulled derict from the database :/

Comment: did you tried to change '%iPhone 6%' with '%".$check."%' ?

Comment: just tryed it now, i ditten work, and when i use this '%".$check."%' the echo of the name is also gone

Comment: ok. let's try another thing. Your code is little bit messy and hard to debug. Try to assign the query string to variable like: $queryString = "SELECT * FROM devices 
                   RIGHT JOIN repair ON devices.name = repair.modelid 
                   WHERE repair.modelid LIKE '%".$check."%'"; Then echo this query and post the result here

Comment: Hello agian, i got it to work now, just movede somethings around, and usede  '%".$check."%'

Thanks you so much! <3

Answer (score 1):

Typos:

```
... WHERE repair.modelid LIKE %iPad%"
```

You didn't quote the `LIKE` clause:

```
... WHERE repair.modelid LIKE '%iPad%'"
                              ^------^--
```

no quotes means `%iPad%` is going to be treated as an unknown/illegal field name, causing an SQL syntax error. Since you have absolutely NO error handling on your query, you simply blindly assume nothing was wrong. Never assume success. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Even some uber-bare-bones error handling like this would have helped:

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: i think your are mis understanding, i need the variable there contains the where =$check

not the other way arround :-/

Comment: same thing holds. you need to produce valid sql, and `where check=$whatever is going to turn that $whatever value into what should be a field name. e.g. `where check=foo` means the DB will be looking for a field name foo, whereas `where check='foo'` will make the db compare the field foo against the string `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if my PHP is a little rusty, but shouldn't this be:

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($dblogin, "select * from devices right join repair on devices.name = repair.modelid WHERE repair.modelid='" . $check . "'");
```

So in the example of $check being "bucket", this would run the SQL:

```
select * from devices right join repair on devices.name = repair.modelid WHERE repaid.modelid='bucket'
```

Comment: i just ran it, but, the output seems to be empty, and it scutten be.

here is an image http://billedeupload.dk/images/r2Gkc.png

the whit text is the echo of $check, and if i entered the text derict in the variable, it will work, but i need it to be dynamic :/

Comment: Have you written a SQL statement outside of PHP and run it directly against the database and it returns results?  If so, post it here.  Ultimately though, you just want to build that same SQL string in PHP before submitting it.  Note: Per somebody else's comment, your code is open to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

If $check will contain only the name of the product, for example "iPad", Change your query like this:

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($dblogin, "select * from devices right join repair on devices.name = repair.modelid WHERE repair.modelid='$check'");
```

UPDATE:

Or for LIKE:

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($dblogin, "select * from devices right join repair on devices.name = repair.modelid WHERE repair.modelid LIKE '%$check%'");
```

Be aware that if $check is coming from the user, this statment is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: You are right, I got confused because I didn't notice that the 2 queries from his question are not the same, and I remembered the "LIKE" statement.

Comment: i tryede this, but, now i got nothing out of the DB by query2 :-/

Comment: Are you sure there is something in the database that matches this?

Comment: Yes, if i put in '%ipad%' raw in the variable, it works just fine, but it will show the same data on every page :), so i pretty lost :S

Comment: The script in my first post, is the complete sql query, but i can post the hole page if it can help

Comment: I will be more specific - are the values in the repair values are 100% match of the values in the devices? If you have "iPhone" in one, and "iphone" in the other, and your database is set on case sensitive collate - that will not match. Try simply to execute the query with a fixed value - NOT USING LIKE, but using "=", and see if you get any results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The brackets around with single quotes. Though you call it id, it is equal to name, so I am assuming not numbers.

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($dblogin, 
    "SELECT * FROM devices 
        RIGHT JOIN repair ON devices.name = repair.modelid 
        WHERE repair.modelid='{$check}'");
```